# Find the total time of all videos (.avi, .flv, .mkv, .mov, .mp4, .swf, .webm, etc.) in a directory using only DOS commands (Windows / .bat) and

Tags: batch-file, time, ms-dos

I would like to have a .bat file that finds the total time of all videos (.avi, .flv, .mkv, .mov, .mp4, .swf, .webm, etc.) in one directory with no other frills.

I want to use only DOS commands (Windows / .bat) and if necessary ffmpeg / ffprobe.
(I don't know Unix/Linux or their commands at all)
I don't want to use PowerShell just pure DOS commands.

The syntax used must be for a .bat file and not for a command line.

Moreover it would be interesting to be able to find the total time for a set of repertoire.

```
\directory 1 > total time 1
\directory 2 > total time 2
…
```

I searched and found the following, but it doesn't give what I want:

---

**#1 – Online DOS Command**

```
for %i in ("*.mp4") do ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "%i" -sexagesimal
```

But it does not give the total time. This gives the time for each file in a directory.

---

**#2 – DOS Batch file (.bat)**

```
  @echo off

˃ output.txt(

      for %%F in (*.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav) do (

          for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (

              'ffprobe "%%F" -show_entries format^=duration -sexagesimal -v quiet -of compact'

          ) do (

              echo %%~nxF^|%%a seconds

          )

      )

  )

  pause
```

The results are in the output.txt file and for each file.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are shooting for.  There are some caveats though.

1. Any file name that has an Ampersand in it will make batch barf while processing.
2. The output ***is in seconds*** having trimmed milliseconds from the calculation.
3. This is for a single directory.  The batch would need to be expanded to walk a directory tree.
4. I am using the `call` batch file function method paired with `goto :EOF` rather than DelayedExpansion.  I personally find it much easier to read and write.
5. This batch expects `ffmpeg` to be in your path and your current directory to be the one you are querying.  I pulled out `pushd D:\stupid_cat_videos` and `popd` before posting.

Notes:
Your ffmpeg command was splicing the time into HH:MM:SS:MS.  I removed the `sexagesimal` param to keep it in seconds.  You can always convert back to HH:MM:SS after the fact.

***I hope this is either what you are looking for or helps you get closer to the prize.***

```bat
    @echo off

    SetLocal

    Set TotalSeconds=0
    Set TotalFiles=0

    for %%F in (*.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav) do call :CountLensOnFile "%%F"

    echo -----------------------------------------
    echo %TotalFiles% files processed.
    echo Total time is %TotalSeconds% seconds.
    echo -----------------------------------------

    goto :EOF

    EndLocal

    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    :CountLensOnFile
    :: Calls ffprobe to calculate file time for input param 1
    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    Set InputFile=%~1
    echo Calculating file time for %InputFile%
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ( 'ffprobe "%InputFile%" -show_entries format^=duration -v quiet -of compact' ) do call :SplitCalcFileTime "%%a"
    Set /a TotalFiles=%TotalFiles% +1
    goto :EOF

    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    :SplitCalcFileTime
    :: Calls for loop to split seconds from miliseconds
    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    Set InputTime=%~1
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%s in ('echo %InputTime%') do call :CalcFileTime "%%s"
    goto :EOF

    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    :CalcFileTime
    :: Calculates total seconds for this run
    :: -----------------------------------------------------
    Set NumSeconds=%~1
    Set /a TotalSeconds = %TotalSeconds% + %NumSeconds%
    goto :EOF
```